# Angular-Ui Router external service in resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to access the `$transition$` object within an external service to resolve a value.

My state definition looks like:

```
$stateProvider.state(
  'detailView.showDocument', {
    url: '/:documentId',
    views: {
      'sidebar': {
        component: 'thumbnailView',
      },
      'main': {
        component: 'mainView',
      }
    },
    params: {
      document: null
    },
    resolve: {
      document: 'resolveDocumentService',
    }
  }
);
```

My service looks like the following:

```
service.$inject =[
    '$transition$',
];

function service(
    $transition$
) {
    // do something 
}
```

This gives an error because the `$transition$` object can not be injected. 
Then I found the solution to use `$uiRouterGlobals` but this seems a bit strange to me.

Is there any reason the `$transition$` object is not avaible within services to resolve a value for a transition?

Comment: You possibly have XY problem. $transition$ is local dependency, and the reason why it's local is that it's local to current state. In your example resolveDocumentService will be a singleton and will be evaluated once, so  $transition$ would be pretty much useless there any way. What exactly do you intend to do with  $transition$ there?

Comment: @Martin which Angular-ui-router version you're using?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @estus' comment, you can change the configuration as follows:

```
resolve: {
  document: [ '$transition$', function($transition$) {
    // write your logic here as `$transition$` will be available here
  } ]
}
```

This function is injectable, and UI router automatically injects the required dependencies into it. Plus, you don't run into the XY problem because you're configuring a particular state.

Comment: Not necessary, AFAIK resolve can have direct dependency name

Answer (score 0):

Yeah my mistake was that the service is of course a singleton. Resolved it with a normal function instead of using a service key.